# How the client can have access to the concreteproducts in Factory pattern

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns, factory

When implementing the Factory Method in c#, I have several concrete products let's say `ConcretProductA` and `ConcretProductB` where every `ConcretProduct` has a public string Name. The problem I am facing is that I need to create a list of all the `ConcretProducts`' names. This list will be used for example to enable the user to select one product in a Combobox on runtime.

So I need the ability to read all the `ConcretProducts`' names, without instantiating instances for all the available `concretProducts`, read the name (i will have to make it static most probably) and store it in an enum for example. If not directly could the interface help me?

Could this work? or there is a better solution?

Comment: Duplicate somehow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450737/factory-pattern-how-to-access-properties-of-concrete-product-classes-from-clien

Comment: A Factory Method cannot know all concrete products. If one method knows all possible concrete products, it is not following the Factory Method pattern; and indeed, there is no need for the Factory Method pattern if all concrete products are known in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Reflection** to do this:

```
public interface IMarkerConcretProducts
{
}

internal class ConcretProductA : IMarkerConcretProducts
{
}

public class ConcretProductB : IMarkerConcretProducts
{
}
```

then get the names of classes

```
var products = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(x => typeof(IMarkerConcretProducts).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract)
            .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 solutions:

a) I would try to find a way to store the product names in a separate list.

b) One possibility would be the use of reflection. If all your products derive from a base type, you could load all derived types from the assembly and propagate the names to the UI.

c) You could put attributes on the classes as well. This way, you can place human readable names on the UI without converting them.

The problem with solutions b and c are that there is no separation of concerns, especially with c, because your domain layer has to know the display names of the products. This could become very difficult with localization as well

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot and the code provided by the answer after solving the issue for me.